# How to combine images into single canvas Android

Tags: android, image, android-canvas

I have this multiple image in a canvas, how do I get the anchors of each image in the canvas and be able to drag, resize and move it on the canvas. Just like in the other image editor  Android applications. Please help me. Thank you

here's the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

        static final int PICKED_ONE = 0;
        static final int PICKED_TWO = 1;

        boolean onePicked = false;
        boolean twoPicked = false;

        Button choosePicture1, choosePicture2;
        ImageView compositeImageView;

        Bitmap bmp1, bmp2;
        Bitmap returnBmp;
        Bitmap drawingBitmap;
        Canvas canvas;
        Paint paint;

        protected static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();
        Bitmap mBackImage, mTopImage, mBackground, mInnerImage, mNewSaving;
        Canvas mComboImage;
        FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream;
        BitmapDrawable mBitmapDrawable;
        private String mCurrent = null;
        private static String mTempDir;
        Button save;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save);

            mTempDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "Pixiedoo" + "/";
            mCurrent = "Aura.png";
            prepareDirectory();

            compositeImageView = (ImageView) this
                    .findViewById(R.id.CompositeImageView);

            choosePicture1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.ChoosePictureButton1);
            choosePicture2 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.ChoosePictureButton2);

            choosePicture1.setOnClickListener(this);
            choosePicture2.setOnClickListener(this);

            save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  Log.v(TAG, "Save Tab Clicked");
                  try {
                    mBitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(drawingBitmap);
                    mNewSaving = ((BitmapDrawable) mBitmapDrawable).getBitmap();
                    String FtoSave = mTempDir + mCurrent;
                    File mFile = new File(FtoSave);
                    mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
                    mNewSaving.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 95, mFileOutputStream);
                    mFileOutputStream.flush();
                    mFileOutputStream.close();
                  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "FileNotFoundExceptionError " + e.toString());
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "IOExceptionError " + e.toString());
                  }
                }
              });
        }
        private boolean prepareDirectory() {
            try {
              if (makeDirectory()) {
                return true;
              } else {
                return false;
              }
            } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              //Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.sdcard_error), 1000).show();
              return false;
            }
          }

        private boolean makeDirectory() {
            File mTempFile = new File(mTempDir);
            if (!mTempFile.exists()) {
              mTempFile.mkdirs();
            }

            if (mTempFile.isDirectory()) {
              File[] mFiles = mTempFile.listFiles();
              for (File mEveryFile : mFiles) {
                if (!mEveryFile.delete()) {
                  //System.out.println(getString(R.string.failed_to_delete) + mEveryFile);
                }
              }
            }
            return (mTempFile.isDirectory());
          }
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int which = -1;

            if (v == choosePicture1) {
                which = PICKED_ONE;
            } else if (v == choosePicture2) {
                which = PICKED_TWO;
            }

            Intent choosePictureIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(choosePictureIntent, which);
        }

        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                Intent intent) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri imageFileUri = intent.getData();

                if (requestCode == PICKED_ONE) {
                    bmp1 = loadBitmap(imageFileUri);
                    onePicked = true;
                } else if (requestCode == PICKED_TWO) {
                    bmp2 = loadBitmap(imageFileUri);
                    twoPicked = true;
                }

                if (onePicked && twoPicked) {
                    drawingBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(),
                            bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
                    canvas = new Canvas(drawingBitmap);
                    paint = new Paint();
                    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, 90, 0, paint);
                //  paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(
                        //  android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));
                    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, 30, 40, paint);


                     compositeImageView.setImageBitmap(drawingBitmap);


                }
            }
        }

        private Bitmap loadBitmap(Uri imageFileUri) {
            Display currentDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

            float dw = currentDisplay.getWidth();
            float dh = currentDisplay.getHeight();

            returnBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) dw, (int) dh,
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);


            try {
                // Load up the image's dimensions not the image itself
                BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                returnBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver()
                        .openInputStream(imageFileUri), null, bmpFactoryOptions);

                int heightRatio = (int) Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight / dh);
                int widthRatio = (int) Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth / dw);

                Log.v("HEIGHTRATIO", "" + heightRatio);
                Log.v("WIDTHRATIO", "" + widthRatio);

                // If both of the ratios are greater than 1, one of the sides of the
                // image is greater than the screen
                if (heightRatio > 1 && widthRatio > 1) {
                    if (heightRatio > widthRatio) {
                        // Height ratio is larger, scale according to it
                        bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = heightRatio;
                    } else {
                        // Width ratio is larger, scale according to it
                        bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = widthRatio;
                    }
                }

                // Decode it for real
                bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                returnBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver()
                        .openInputStream(imageFileUri), null, bmpFactoryOptions);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.v("ERROR", e.toString());
            }

            return returnBmp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: did u tried this:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740362/merge-two-bitmaps-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740362/merge-two-bitmaps-in-android)

Comment: @MD edit your link... you should direct it to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740362/merge-two-bitmaps-in-android