# Check value and checkbox will be checked Android

Tags: android, string, checkbox

I have this code wherein it comes from an intent. The variable is status and such could be `final` or  `notfinal` 
I was able to alert if I have passed the variable in my current intent. And it shows such alert. Moreover, I want 
that my checkbox in my xml will be checked if the status value is `final` and if not there will be no check at all. And such does not work. Any help will do. Thanks!
Here's my code snippet:

```
status = i.getString("a_status");
//alert(status);
if (status =="notfinal")
final_checkbox.setChecked(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't compare tow `String` using `==`. You have compare as `string1.equals(string2)`...It will be better to use `equalsIgnoreCase()` than `equals()`.

```
if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("notfinal")){
        final_checkbox.setChecked(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way: instead of `==` operator used `string.equals(`) method

```
   if (status.equals("final")){

     final_checkbox.setChecked(true);

     }else{

     //do something
     }
```

Comment: Do you know or have any idea on how to put multiple images in canvas in Android? @M D

Comment: here it is  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871913/how-to-combine-images-into-single-canvas-android

Answer (score 0):

compare the String using `equals()`

change this `if (status =="notfinal")` to `if (status .equals("notfinal"))`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if your status may take just two values, I'd suggest using a `Boolean` variable instead a `String`.

Said that, you're getting the value by calling `.getString()`. You should call `getStringExtra()` instead as this returns the extras you might have provided at call time. And if you finally use a `String`, use `.equals()` or `equalsIgnoreCase()` instead. For instance:

```
if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("notfinal")) { ... }
```