# Merge two images one below the other in android by adding pixels

Tags: android

I am trying to join images and form 1 single image.This is done to send the image to the server.

```
    //Obtain the bitmaps from drawabl folder
    Bitmap bm1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
    Bitmap bm2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img);
    //Create a buffer
   ByteBuffer buffer3 = ByteBuffer.allocate((bm1.getHeight()+bm2.getHeight()) *        (bm1.getRowBytes()+bm2.getRowBytes()));
    //copy the pixels to buffer
        bm2.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer3);
        bm1.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer3);
    //Covert to byteArray
        byte[] bytes = buffer3.array();
        int leftovers = buffer3.remaining();
        buffer3.compact();

//Finally forming a bitmap

  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes , 0, bytes.length);   
  ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgV);
  img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

But the problem I am facing is my "bitmap" is coming as null.

Can anyone please help me joining images.

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740362/merge-two-bitmaps-in-android

Comment: I don't want to merge just to display the image in android.I have to send it to the server and hence I can't use canvas.

Comment: You just contradicted your questions title, as i understand, you want to merge, display and send, and if im not wrong the canvas could return a bitmap with its content.

Comment: May be I wasn't able to express well...I want to merge the images like adding images one below the other and then send to server.I can't send a canvas to the server as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks Nanoc I understook what you said.Canvas helped me and I got what I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you can use canvas like as follows

```
   public Bitmap mergeBitmap(Bitmap bitmap1, Bitmap bitmap2) {
    Bitmap mergedBitmap = null;

    int w, h = 0;

    h = bitmap1.getHeight() + bitmap2.getHeight();
    if (bitmap1.getWidth() > bitmap2.getWidth()) {
        w = bitmap1.getWidth();
    } else {
        w = bitmap2.getWidth();
    }

    mergedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mergedBitmap);

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, 0f, 0f, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap2, 0f, bitmap1.getHeight(), null);


    return mergedBitmap;
}
```

Comment: Small improvement: Use `int w = Math.max(bitmap1.getWidth(), bitmap2.getWidth());` instead of the 5-line if construction.

Comment: it helps me enough i was trying from a day but not found any method that can help me finally this method works me ..thanks