# How to Draw a Pattern on Bitmap using canvas

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap

I just want to know is there anyway to draw a pattern over a bitmap , [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgHws.jpg). For example, I want to draw a pattern of this over my bitmap. [image]

Comment: see `PorterDuffXfermode`, some background [here](http://ssp.impulsetrain.com/porterduff.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1: Transparent Foreground**

If you follow the process described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11740362/7128655) to merge the two images, you can draw one image onto another. Simply change the opacity of the top-most image as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5118894/7128655). Consider the following example:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(/* width */, /* height */, Config.ARGB_8888);
Paint alpha = new Paint();
alpha.setAlpha(/* alpha */);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
Bitmap background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
    getResources(), R.drawable.background);
Bitmap foreground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
    getResources(), R.drawable.pattern);
canvas.drawBitmap(background, /* xPos */, /* yPos */, null);
canvas.drawBitmap(foreground, /* xPos */, /* yPos */, alpha);
```

**Option 2: Background Masked with Foreground**

Alternatively, if you are trying to mask the image, you can consider implementing the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26031133/7128655).

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely set a bitmap.And creating a canvas over it.Once canvas gets created over the bitmap, you can definitely draw custom patterns over it.

You can see the complete guide how to draw text here:

https://www.skoumal.net/en/android-how-draw-text-bitmap/

Long story short:

Copy your bitmap to make it mutable and create Canvas based on it.